# Create more data by creating a block of 'past' for each row, for LSTM input

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lstm

I have the dataset which looks at user behaviour on my website every day. I simply record the number of page views viewed (for simplicity only 1 feature) and want to make a prediction whether the person will buy a product or not.

I've decided to model this using and LSTM network.

**Goal:** For each block of **n=3** (ordered) days, output whether the conversion happened within 2 months. In short, for each row, apply the following: Look for n visits in the past. Look 2 months into future to see if conversion happened.

---

I have 2 dataframes: 1st one contains users previous behaviour and 2nd contains the day of their conversion.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2], 'date':[20180311,20180310,20180210,20170505,20180312,20180311], 'page_views':[10,20,45,1,14,15],'conversion':[1,1,1,1,0,0]})
conversion_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user_id':[1], 'conversion':[20180312]})

   conversion      date  page_views  user_id
0           1  20180311          10        1
1           1  20180310          20        1
2           1  20180210          45        1
3           1  20170505           1        1
4           0  20180312          14        2
5           0  20180311          15        2

   conversion  user_id
0    20180312        1
```

I would like to predict all conversions within 2 months. For example let's look at user 1. Given the look-forward window of 2 months with n=3 timesteps, we have the following data in LSTM:

**Desired output:**

```
X = [
[[10],[20],[45]], # looking at last 3 timesteps, recording pageviews
[[20],[45],[1]], 
[[45],[1],[0]],
[[1],[0],[0]], # done with user 1, next user
[[14],[15],[0]],
[[15],[0],[0]]
]

Y = [1,1,1,0,0,0] # 4th observation is not 1, because the conversion happened after 2 month look-forward window.
```

**Alternative desired output:** by adding `date` to index using `set_index()`

```
                     page_views    conversion
user_id       date 
1       | 20180311   10            1
        |            20            1
        |            45            1
----------------------------------------------
1       | 20180310   20            1
                     45            1
                     1             1
----------------------------------------------
1       | 20180210   45            1
                      1            1
                      0            1
----------------------------------------------
1       | 20170505    1            0
                      0            0
                      0            0
----------------------------------------------
2       | 20180312   14            0
                     15            0
                      0            0
.....
```

Currently I am using `pd.to_panel()` to get 3 dimensional output, and I only get the latest **n** days using `df.group_by('user_id').head(n)`. My current approach would give me 2 data points with a strict restriction that conversion will happen next time they visit the site. E.g. for `user_id=1` we have *VVVVVC* (5 visits that led to conversion on next day - 20180312), my current model would take *VV-**VVV**-C* and predict next visit-day conversions.

Instead, the new way will predict conversions 2months into the future and I get more data for free (also a better model). But as an additional constraint, I would like the code to be < O(n^2).